# Removing unwanted xml content using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0 and I'm trying to do this xml-to-xml transformation :

My input.xml:

```
<RootElement>
  <CustomAttr name="GVillage"/>
  .
  .
  <CustomAttr name="RVC">
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name="RVC">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
  </CustomAttr>
  <CustomAttr name="GTX">
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name="GTX">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
  </CustomAttr>
  .
  .
  .
  <CustomAttr name=".......">
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name=".......">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
  </CustomAttr>
  <CustomAttr name="mode" value="DummyValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="affinity" value="SomeValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="names" value="SampleValue">
    <list>
      <value>nodevalue</value>
    </list>
  </CustomAttr>
</RootElement>
```

My expected output.xml :

```
<RootElement>
  <CustomAttr name="GVillage"/>
  .
  .
  <CustomAttr name="ShortCodes">
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name="RVC">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name="GTX">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
  .
  .
  .
    <ValStart>
      <RetailAttr name=".......">
        .
        .
      </RetailAttr>
    </ValStart>
  </CustomAttr>
  <CustomAttr name="mode" value="DummyValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="affinity" value="SomeValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="names" value="SampleValue">
    <list>
      <value>nodevalue</value>
    </list>
  </CustomAttr>
</RootElement>
```

The input xml has elements `<CustomAttr name="RVC">`, `<CustomAttr name="GTX">` and following subsequent any number of `<CustomAttr name=".......">` which I've tried to generalize and show using ".....". I need to combine all these elements into one single element `<CustomAttr name="ShortCodes">` which opens once at the beginning and closes once at the end (as shown in the output.xml) instead of opening and closing each time for every `<RetailAttr name="RVC">` , `<RetailAttr name="GTX">` etc. respectively.

The XSLT I have currently is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="CustomAttr[@name='RVC']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">ShortCodes</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//CustomAttr/ValStart"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I am getting from this XSLT is xsltoutput.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootElement>
<CustomAttr name="GVillage"></CustomAttr>
  .
  .
<CustomAttr name="ShortCodes">
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name="RVC">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name="GTX">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name=".......">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
</CustomAttr>
<CustomAttr name="GTX">
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name="GTX">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
</CustomAttr>
  .
  .
  .
<CustomAttr name=".......">
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name=".......">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
</CustomAttr>
  <CustomAttr name="mode" value="DummyValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="affinity" value="SomeValue"/>
  <CustomAttr name="names" value="SampleValue">
    <list>
      <value>nodevalue</value>
    </list>
  </CustomAttr>
</RootElement>
```

I am getting the transform I need, but I am getting unwanted content copied as well which is after `</CustomAttr>` (the closing element for `<CustomAttr name="ShortCodes">`) in xsltoutput.xml which I am not able to understand how to remove.

The unwanted content in xsltoutput.xml which I want to remove :

```
<CustomAttr name="GTX">
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name="GTX">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
</CustomAttr>
  .
  .
  .
<CustomAttr name=".......">
<ValStart>
<RetailAttr name=".......">
        .
        .
</RetailAttr>
</ValStart>
</CustomAttr>
```

Since there can be any number of CustomAttr elements as per my input xml requirement so I am trying for a generalized XSLT. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: What are the criteria for deciding that GTX, RVC, etc go in the combined shortCodes element, while mode, affinity, etc don't? Is it the fact that the name is three characters long?

Comment: Hi Michael..so the criteria is the elements having `ValStart` (like GTX, RVC) will go in the combined ShortCodes element. And mode, affinity and names won't go in it since it doesn't contain the `ValStart` element. I have tried Martin's code and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the identity transformation is a good starting point but if you use it, it looks as if you need `<xsl:template match="CustomAttr[preceding-sibling::CustomAttr[@name='RVC']]"/>` to block the copying of those elements.

Based on your comment and edit, doing `<xsl:template match="CustomAttr[ValStart and preceding-sibling::CustomAttr[@name='RVC']]"/>` might do.

Comment: Hi @Martin, so the "..." I had in my input and output xml right before the `</RootElement>`, that section contains 3 `<CustomAttr>` elements for **mode**, **affinity** and **names** (I have edited my post to show that)..the code which you've given, removes those 3 CustomAttr elements as well which I need to retain. My apologies for not adding them earlier, while generalizing the code I accidentally removed those 3 CustomAttr required elements as well.

Comment: So what defines which elements are merged and which not? I have made an edit that should keep empty `CustomAttr`.

Comment: out of those 3 `<CustomAttr>` elements, **mode** and **affinity** will be as it is with just a name and value attribute. But for `<CustomAttr name="names" value="SampleValue">`, it will contain a `<list>` element inside it.

Comment: As in the other template you select all `ValStart`, I have changed the predicate to block elements that have a `ValStart` child.